# Google search engine not removing old pages

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

I have a website and yesterday I renamed all the HTML files to appropriate names to help them show up in searches better. For example one of my pages was called `logic.html` now its called `logic_gates_and_truth_tables.html`.

I submitted a new site map to Google and told it to recrawl my site and today I did a `site:example.com` search and the search results had doubled because it kept"logic.html" in its results and added a new result called `logic_gates_and_truth_tables`. As you would expect when clicking the old link it gives you a "page not found" error.

How can I get Google to remove the old pages and only list the newly renamed pages?

Answer (score 1):

This question already has been [answered here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63458/google-is-still-crawling-and-indexing-my-old-dummy-test-pages-which-now-are-40).

The short version is that it can take up to 30-60 days for Google to remove them from the index. Let the pages display a 404, as they do now, and after a while Google will stop looking for them and remove them from the index.